# Exchange student traveling in and out of the US on student visa

Tags: exchange, study, japanese-language

I have a Japanese exchange student living with us in the United States, we are traveling to Mexico for vacation. I am worried about her returning to the US with us. She is on a student visa. What does she need to do to make sure our return trip from Mexico to the States goes without incident?